# ajax request for multiple data in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm getting my data with `load more button` and everything is working fine, the issue is when i have second table Ajax request it won't execute.

## Sample

`controller`

```
$jobs = Job::where('status', '1')->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
if ($request->ajax()) {
  $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
  return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
}
return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
```

**This code above loads my jobs of page `2,3,4,etc.` with `load more button` and it's working.**

**Now**, when I try to use same file and request but this time for another table it stops working:

`controller`

```
$jobs = Job::where('status', '1')->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
$portfolios = Portfolio::orderby('id', 'desc')->where('status', '1')->paginate(4);

if ($request->ajax()) {
  $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
  return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
}

if($page->template == 'portfolio'){
  return view('front.pages.portfolio', compact('page', 'portfolios'));
} elseif($page->template == 'job'){
  return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
}
```

and then my `front.pages.test` is look like:

```
@if(isset($jobs))
  @foreach($jobs as $job)
    html of my jobs style etc....
  @endforeach
@elseif(isset($portfolios))
  @foreach($portfolios as $portfolio)
    html of my portfolios style etc....
  @endforeach
@endif
```

## Question

1. Why when I add second `compact` to my Ajax request it stop functioning?
2. How can I fix it? (I will need to add more compact in this function later)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.

> the issue is when i have second table Ajax request it won't execute.

```
if ($request->ajax()) { //<-- second request is ajax is it not?
    $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
     return response()->json(['html'=>$view]); //<--- return
}

//< --- as you said it's never executed -->
if($page->template == 'portfolio'){
  return view('front.pages.portfolio', compact('page', 'portfolios'));
 } elseif($page->template == 'job'){
  return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
}
```

See your second request passes this text `if ($request->ajax()) { return ...}`- As this ia above your code it never reaches the new code because it returns in that condition. To be clear, you said both request were AJAX, so that's what happens in that case.

You should send another piece of data like mode that you can use to switch the operation on. Or some other method to differentiate between them.

PS - I don't use Laravel, so I don't know the Laravel approved way to do that, but it should be rather trivial.

## **Update**

I will explain it further.

Now please understand, where these requests come from, and what they should do or what order they are in doesn't really matter. The **only** thing that matters is they call the same piece of code for *both* of them and they are *both* AJAX requests.

### First request

---

So lets run through this for the first one, step by step:

1. You send first AJAX request
2. It runs the above code, In the first condition `if($request->ajax())`or in English it asks: "is this request a AJAX request?" which we said it is. So that passes
3. The code assigns this - `$view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));`
4. We return our response `return response()->json(['html'=>$view]); //<--- return` which exits out of this (whatever "it" is) because of the return, and none of the code below #4 runs.

To visualize this I numbed the lines below:

```
/*2*/   if ($request->ajax()) { //<-- second request is ajax is it not?
/*3*/       $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
/*4*/       return response()->json(['html'=>$view]); //<--- return
/*exit*/ }         

        //< --- as you said it's never executed -->
        if($page->template == 'portfolio'){
          return view('front.pages.portfolio', compact('page', 'portfolios'));
         } elseif($page->template == 'job'){
          return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
        }
```

So far so good.

### Second request

---

Now lets walk though the second request the same way (literally):

1. You send second AJAX request
2. It runs the above code, In the first condition `if($request->ajax())`or in English it asks: "is this request a AJAX request?" which we said it is. So that passes
3. The code assigns this - `$view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));`
4. We return our response `return response()->json(['html'=>$view]); //<--- return` which exits out of this (whatever "it" is) because of the return, and none of the code below #4 runs.

To visualize this I numbed the lines below:

```
/*2*/   if ($request->ajax()) { //<-- second request is ajax is it not?
/*3*/       $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
/*4*/       return response()->json(['html'=>$view]); //<--- return
/*exit*/ }       

        //< --- as you said it's never executed -->
        if($page->template == 'portfolio'){
          return view('front.pages.portfolio', compact('page', 'portfolios'));
         } elseif($page->template == 'job'){
          return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
        }
```

Look familiar?

Well it should it's exactly the same as the first one. As I said a few times now, because both requests are AJAX and this code first checks if they are AJAX. Only the first block of code is ran.

### Solution

---

So what can you do, as I said I don't use Laravel so there is no way for me to know if your new code will even work.  All I can go by is the few lines of code that was posted and your description of the problem. Therefor, the only way I can show you how to fix this is to re-arange it.  That way all I am doing is moving a few things around.

Which is fine because I can fix it with just that.  Maybe it won't be the best way to fix it.  But it will make your code run, of that I am sure.

```
if ($request->ajax()) { 
   if($page->template == 'portfolio'){
        return view('front.pages.portfolio', compact('page', 'portfolios'));
   } elseif($page->template == 'job'){
        return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
   }else{
       $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
       return response()->json(['html'=>$view]); //<--- return
   }
}
```

Lets run though this one:

1. You make first request
2. It runs the new code, In the first condition `if($request->ajax())`or in English it asks: "is this request a AJAX request?" which we said it is. So that passes
3. Now we are at the first part of the inner condition or this line

   - `if($page->template == 'portfolio'){`  Which says is Page Tempate equal to "portfolio". I moved the number down a row for "readabillity" reasons.
   - If the above is FALSE we hit the second one `} elseif($page->template == 'job'){` same as above, but were checking `$page` for "job" this time.
   - If the above is FALSE we hit the third one `}else{` which is always true, so if none of the other 2 conditions passed we run the orignal one which is the code in this block.

To visualize this I numbed the lines below

```
/*2*/   if ($request->ajax()) { 
/*3*/      if($page->template == 'portfolio'){
/*3.1*/         return view('front.pages.portfolio', compact('page', 'portfolios'));
           } elseif($page->template == 'job'){
/*3.2*/         return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
           }else{
/*3.3*/         $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
                return response()->json(['html'=>$view]); //<--- return
           }
       }
```

As you can see we will now hit all of our inner conditions when they are AJAX requests, which you said the are.  And as I mentioned at the start of this exercise it dosn't matter what these do or what order they are in. The same is true here.  Also as I did above in the **Second Request** section.

If you make another request (against this new code) It will run exactly the same as the first one here, in the **Solution** section did.

Basically the code in either case doens't care where they came from, it treats every request as a new one. HTTP is stateless, that is why we need Cookies an Databases and so on.  The difference (between the original code and the new stuff) is the second request here (in the new stuff) has access to all of 3, where we have another set of conditions to direct us to the proper output.

So say we run the above up to #3, then `$page` in this request is equal to `job` we run this code:

```
 /*3.2*/   return view('front.pages.job', compact('page', 'jobs'));
```

Now say we do another, but this time `$page` is not equal to `job` and it's also not equal to `portfolio`. Well in this case we execute the `else` block with this code:

```
/*3.3*/   $view = (String) view('front.pages.test',compact('jobs', 'portfolios'));
```

And so on for however many requests you want to make.

### Conclusion

---

Now you have to understand I have no idea if this thing `$page` is even set, ect.  But provided your code above is the way it's supposed to be in Laravel, this should execute those new calls. Rather or not they will work, I have no idea.  But, I suppose you'll find that out.

I really hope that makes sense, because your comment really didn't.

> Now, when I try to use same file and request but this time for another table it stops working

The reason it stops working is your sending data for Table2 with a different structure. The columns are probably different if it's a different table, data is different too etc... But you are running that though the code for the first or the original table you had.

I really don't  know how else to say it.  There are probably other issue as well, but this will at least allow it to run your code.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, to answer your question `second request is ajax is it not?` i should say YES. By second request i meant portfolios ajax request however first request was ajax as well but in different blade file. To make it more clear: first ajax request comes from `pages.job` and it gets more jobs in that blade, second request comes from `pages.portfolios` and it gets more portfolio in it&#39;s own blade.
About your suggestion `getting extra validator like mode etc.` i think `isset` in my `test.blade` file will do that in order to see if request was from jobs or portfolios. Ideas?

Comment: I don't know what a blade template has to do with this.  But you would need to tell the AJAX request apart instead of using `$request->ajax()` above